# How to replace question mark in value of a panda frame as missing value?

Tags: python, pandas

This is the code I have used:

```
diabetic_df.replace({'weight': {'?': ""}}, regex=False)
```

However it does not show up as missing value when I run the code below"

```
diabetic_df.isnull().sum()
```

Would you be able to advise what I have done wrong?

Comment: try this `df.replace('?',np.nan
)`

Comment: @pyd add your comment as an answer :)

Comment: added, @user1055395

Comment: I have tried diabetic_df.replace('?',np.nan ) and it is able to replaced all the ? with NaN. However when I run the command diabetic_df.isnull().sum(), all the attributes still show up with no missing value. Is there anything else that I have missed out?

Comment: thanks. gotten it working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are replacing to empty string not NaN
try this,

```
import numpy as np

diabetic_df.replace({'weight': {'?': np.nan}}, regex=False,inplace=True)
diabetic_df.isnull().sum()
```

Comment: thanks. it at least shows the missing value as NaN. However when I run  diabetic_df.isnull().sum(), weight still show up as zero missing value.

Comment: I added 'inplace' please try the latest edit and see

Comment: I have gotten it 
df2 = diabetic_df.replace('?',np.nan )  
df2.isnull().sum()

Answer (score 1):

some times there will be white spaces with the ? in the file generated by systems like informatica or HANA

first you Need to strip the white spaces in the DataFrame

```
temp_df_trimmed = temp_df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip() if x.dtype == "object" else x)
```

And later apply the function to replace the data

```
temp_df_trimmed['RC'] = temp_df_trimmed['RC'].map(lambda x: np.nan if x=="?"  else x)
```